# Is Star Trek Online part of the Star Trek universe/timeline?

Tags: star-trek

Are the events in Star Trek Online technically part of the Star Trek timeline? If not, why not? To my knowledge, CBS has to approve everything they put into STO. Does that make it official Star Trek? It obviously has the license...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, only the TV shows and Movies are considered canon.

From [Star Trek's Official Website](http://web.archive.org/web/20100628174255/http://www.startrek.com/startrek/view/help/faqs/faq/676.html):

> As a rule of thumb, the events that take place within the live-action episodes and movies are canon, or official Star Trek facts. Story lines, characters, events, stardates, etc. that take place within the fictional novels, video games, the Animated Series, and the various comic lines have traditionally not been considered part of the canon.